# How to generate a mask for knight?

Tags: chess

I'm using bitboards to implement a chess program. My question is basically when I move a knight, it's mask has to be modified to get the legal moves. Is there an elegant way for it, I was thinking about shifting bits but that seems to be a bad way.

Answer (score 2):

As there are only 64 squares on the board, you can simply precompute all knight moves. Within the search itself, you can then find the knight's attacks by one table lookup.

The table itself will only take 512 bytes (64*8 bytes).

Initially filling the table is not time critical, so the choice of algorithm does not matter very much, as long as it comes up with the correct squares.